# Images not staying in place using position:sticky

Tags: position, sticky

I am trying to use the sticky position to keep two images in place when a user access my site (PHP) via their mobile. But despite setting position to sticky it still doesn't stay in place.

my code: ( CSS )

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 736px)
{


.logo{
position:sticky;
top:2%;
left:6%;
Width:43%
}

.mbanner{
position:sticky;
top:10%;
left:52%;
width:48%
}
```

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested your code and works fine on iphone 7.
Since it's on Safari you will need to add:

position: -webkit-sticky;

Also add to html metadata:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Finally CSS shoule be:

```css
@media screen and (max-device-width: 736px){

.logo{
position:sticky;
position: -webkit-sticky;
top:2%;
left:6%;
Width:43%
}

.mbanner{
position:sticky;
position: -webkit-sticky;
top:10%;
left:52%;
width:48%
}
```

Comment: Problem is when i test it on my i phone 8 plus, it doesnt work ? :(

Comment: Give me time to check it on my iphone 7. If you have the whole code it would be better i think. Since it's safari on iphone, add position: -webkit-sticky;

Comment: Check initial answer. I will edit it. Just tested on iphone 7 and works fine.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.

Comment: Happy to help! If you can, please upvote my answer because i am new user. Thank you!